# Sending messages in a cycle

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to edit my old bot from being command based to automatic on the start. Previously I've had this:

```
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx, channelid, time):
    channel_id = int(channelid)
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    sleeptime = int(time)

    loopcheck = 0
    while 1:
        if loopcheck == len(SElist):
            loopcheck = int(0)
        loopcheck = loopcheck + 1
        await channel.send(random.choice(SElist))
        print(f'Sent message to #{channel.name}')
        await asyncio.sleep(sleeptime)
```

It would send message to channel and it would keep sending it each sleeptime seconds value. Command would look like this:

```
+start 192839345345812312 10
```

Channel is made up but you get it. I'm trying to make it do it on the start:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():

    with open("channels.json", "r") as read_file:
        decodedArray = json.load(read_file)

        finalNumpyArrayOne = numpy.asarray(decodedArray["channels"])
        for x in finalNumpyArrayOne:
            print(x[0])
            async def start(ctx, channelid, time):
                channel_id = int(x[0])
                channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
                sleeptime = int(x[1])
                await channel.send(random.choice(SElist))
                await asyncio.sleep(sleeptime)
```

I want it to start this cycle of sending messages on the start for each item (channel and seconds) in array from json file.
But I'm obviously doing it wrong. And need some help with it please as the code for async def start doesn't run.

Comment: You're never calling that start function, you just created it. It obviously won't run. Also, ``ext.tasks`` is a much better fit for this. Don't do this type of stuff in ``on_ready``.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and use `tasks` to execute a pre defined async function when the bot starts.

```
@client.listen()
async def on_ready():
    <function_name>.start()

@tasks.loop(seconds=86400)
async def <function_name>():
    print('foo')
client.run('TOKEN')
```

where seconds equals the amount of seconds you want to wait between each function call.
discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html